# python evaluate functions with parameters given by a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

With python how can I evaluate a dictionary of functions with their associate parameters. To be more specific, the keys are the functions and the values are a list of paramters.

for example, consider the dictionary:

```
{f1: [a, b, c], f2: [q], f3: [5, c]}
```

How would I iterate over the functions to compute:

```
f1(a, b, c)
f2(q)
f3(5, c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternately:

```
for key in dct:
    key(*dct[key])
```

Answer (score 8):

```
for func, args in the_dictionary.items():
    func(*args)
```

Comment: `for func, args in the_dictionary.iteritems(): func(*args)` dictionary often raises ToManyValuesToUnpack Error

Comment: it was `for func, args in the_dictionary:` then i see it =)

Answer (score 2):

Arguments in lists can be unpacked by appending an asterisk to the front of them.  They then act as if they were supplied one at a time in order.

```
for func in func_args.keys():
    func(*(func_args[func]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
def f1(x, y, z):
    print 'f1', x, y, x

def f2(x):
    print 'f2', x

def f3(x, y):
    print 'f2', x, y

myDict = { 'f1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'f2': ['q'], 'f3': [5, 'c'] }

for k, v in myDict.items():
    globals()[k](*v)
```